# X11 forwarding affects Java Swing GUI dropdowns - Items not selectable, Menus collapse immediately

Tags: java, linux, swing, x11

Have a Java Swing app that is running on a Linux server and is being X displayed back via X11 forwarding. Cygwin is running on my workstation. Connection is made to the server using PuTTY with X11 forwarding and then ssh -XY .

Application launches just fine, but certain GUI elements (mostly drop down menus) do not behave correctly. Some menus close immediately after they are opened (the blink open/close when clicked.) Others will not select / highlight items using the mouse. Others will select different items than the one hovered over by my house.

The application works just fine on Windows or on Linux when invoked directed. Problem seems specifically related to viewing it through X11.

Is it possible X11 is swallowing some GUI events or not repainting fast enough?

Comment: You might experiment with different window managers.

Answer (score 0):

This questions seems quiet old but I just had the same issue.

A solution may be to use compression (-C) and an other algorithm (which is faster) for the connection (-c cipher1, cipher2).

Eg. :

```
ssh -X -C -c blowfish-cbc,arcfour username@host
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I tried this and it did not help. What's strange is that it seems to only be the dropdownlist that's slow. You click the drop down list to get the list of options, and it takes ~14 seconds for the list of options to appear. Everything else is interactive.